# SQUID not caching anything

Tags: squid

I am trying to setup squid to cache downloading of one of my programs , unfortunately I found out I am not caching anything, my logs looks like:

```
1414421675.540   1059 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/204 288 GET http://serverfault.com/posts/596890/ivc/d85b? - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 -
1414421676.548    769 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1539 GET http://careers.stackoverflow.com/gethired/js - DIRECT/198.252.206.17 text/javascript
1414421677.226    674 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/204 442 GET http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ad/i/o8dlwjVTTd7-lrgGzmMcoFk-2LAw8 - DIRECT/198.252.206.17 image/gif
1414421685.217     48 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 4345 GET http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/SEARCH_TREE/ - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 text/html
1414421685.273     44 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1407 GET http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/SEARCH_TREE/INDEX.DEF - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 text/plain
1414421689.198    553 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 16838 GET http://serverfault.com/questions/473940/caching-large-amounts-of-data - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 text/html
1414421689.276     35 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1983 GET https://i.stack.imgur.com/F801B.jpg? - DIRECT/103.31.6.34 image/jpeg
1414421689.426     27 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 614 GET http://www.google-analytics.com/collect? - DIRECT/173.194.40.5 image/gif
1414421689.438     32 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/204 395 GET http://b.scorecardresearch.com/b? - DIRECT/193.247.167.139 -
1414421689.517    138 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 2615 GET http://engine.adzerk.net/ados? - DIRECT/107.20.144.218 application/javascript
1414421689.594    190 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 439 GET http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel;r=545276160;a=p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc;fpan=0;fpa=P0-1294698880-1407227396456;ns=0;ce=1;cm=;je=1;sr=1920x1080x24;enc=n;dst=1;et=1414421689399;tzo=-60;ref=http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fquestions%2Fask;url=http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fquestions%2F473940%2Fcaching-large-amounts-of-data;ogl=type.website%2Cimage.http%3A%2F%2Fcdn%252Esstatic%252Enet%2Fserverfault%2Fimg%2Fapple-touch-icon%402%252Epng%3Fv%3D9b1f48ae296b%2Ctitle.Caching%20large%20amounts%20of%20data%2Cdescription.We%20need%20to%20cache%20all%20psd%2Fzip%20files%20from%20our%20amazone%20S3%20storage%252E%20The%20amount%20of%20th%2Curl.http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault%252Ecom%2Fquestions%2F473940%2Fcaching-large-amounts-of-data - DIRECT/95.172.94.12 image/gif
1414421689.996    214 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1036 GET http://stackexchange.com/ads/launched-question/js? - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 text/javascript
1414421690.007    228 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 671 GET http://engine.adzerk.net/i.gif? - DIRECT/23.23.234.111 image/gif
1414421690.093    651 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/204 288 GET http://serverfault.com/posts/473940/ivc/d85b? - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 -
1414421690.128    119 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 671 GET http://engine.adzerk.net/i.gif? - DIRECT/23.23.234.111 image/gif
1414421690.229    153 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 3163 GET http://ad.doubleclick.net/adj/N7384.171779.STACKOVERFLOW.COM/B8285612.111984239;sz=728x90;click=http://engine.adzerk.net/r? - DIRECT/173.194.40.27 text/javascript
1414421690.320     42 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 6968 GET http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/launched-ads/physics.png - DIRECT/141.101.114.59 image/png
1414421690.369    126 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 603 GET http://googleads4.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/adview? - DIRECT/173.194.40.13 text/html
1414421690.641    103 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 10047 GET http://s1.2mdn.net/viewad/3742665/SignUp-BannerAds-CodeBugs-c-728x90.gif - DIRECT/74.125.232.156 image/gif
1414421691.158    379 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/204 442 GET http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ad/i/o8dlwjVTTd7-lrgGzmMcoFk-2LAw8 - DIRECT/198.252.206.17 image/gif
1414421692.532    669 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 529 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1414421693.656  19965 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 5076 CONNECT adzerk-www.s3.amazonaws.com:443 - DIRECT/54.231.1.233 -
1414421699.259  23788 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1560 CONNECT qa.sockets.stackexchange.com:443 - DIRECT/198.252.206.25 -
1414421700.747     91 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 677 GET http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/activeview? - DIRECT/173.194.112.218 image/gif
1414421709.400    141 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 29779 GET http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/ - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 text/html
1414421710.792   1349 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1858526 GET http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/MASTER_APP/FULL/MODEL/GRAPHIC/0000/GRA/0000A5/0000A5.GFF.ZIP - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 application/x-zip-compressed
1414421711.121    297 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 439819 GET http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/MASTER_APP/FULL/MODEL/GRAPHIC/0000/GRA/0000R8/0000R8.GFF.ZIP - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 application/x-zip-compressed
1414421711.518    370 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 508209 GET http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/MASTER_APP/FULL/MODEL/GRAPHIC/0000/GRA/0JD050/0JD050.GFF.ZIP - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 application/x-zip-compressed
1414421711.665     52 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 29779 GET http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/ - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 text/html
1414421712.270    548 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/204 262 PUT http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/LOG/347035-20141027155316-STATUS.LOG - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 -
1414421712.911    127 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/204 262 PUT http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/LOG/347035-20141027155316-STATUS.LOG - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 -
1414421713.531     83 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 3382 GET http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/LOG/347035-20141027155316-STATUS.LOG - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 text/plain
1414421715.584     42 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/204 262 PUT http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/TRACE/347035-20141027.ZIP - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 -
1414421717.463   1878 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/204 262 PUT http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/TRACE/347035-20141027.ZIP - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 -
1414421738.346    588 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 392 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1414421784.008    258 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 392 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1414421830.045    298 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 392 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1414421839.845     51 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1624 CONNECT autodiscover.audatex.cz:443 - DIRECT/86.110.226.145 -
1414421839.849     55 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1624 CONNECT autodiscover.audatex.cz:443 - DIRECT/86.110.226.145 -
1414421845.898   5052 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 2940 CONNECT autodiscover.audatex.cz:443 - DIRECT/86.110.226.145 -
1414421845.908   5057 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 2908 CONNECT autodiscover.audatex.cz:443 - DIRECT/86.110.226.145 -
1414421855.023 200872 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 9839 CONNECT www.gravatar.com:443 - DIRECT/68.232.35.121 -
1414421876.367    622 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 392 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1414421889.871 199446 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 1560 CONNECT qa.sockets.stackexchange.com:443 - DIRECT/198.252.206.25 -
1414421894.153    358 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 17472 GET http://serverfault.com/search/titles? - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1414421894.399    229 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/204 306 POST http://serverfault.com/gps/event - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 -
1414421896.276    275 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 17554 GET http://serverfault.com/search/titles? - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1414421896.510    233 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 392 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/validate-title - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1414421896.851    340 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/204 306 POST http://serverfault.com/gps/event - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 -
1414421921.868    499 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 391 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/0/editor-heartbeat/ask - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1414421929.372 292573 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 4556 CONNECT clients1.google.com:443 - DIRECT/173.194.112.199 -
1414421941.513    334 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 392 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/validate-body - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1414421943.762    235 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 392 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/validate-body - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
1414421949.862    476 127.0.0.1 TCP_MISS/200 392 POST http://serverfault.com/posts/validate-body - DIRECT/198.252.206.16 application/json
```

So it looks it logging what i did, and also log which files program download

```
http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/MASTER_APP/FULL/MODEL/GRAPHIC/0000/GRA/0JD050/0JD050.GFF.ZIP - DIRECT/93.189.233.60 application/x-zip-compressed
```

Anyway when I try to download same file again it is downloaded again from the original webserver instead of from cache. Same when I try to watch some video or anything, it is always downloading , never served from cache. Adding my config as well. Can anybody tell me where can be a problem?

The sanitised config is below:

```
acl all src all
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80      # http
acl Safe_ports port 21      # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443     # https
acl Safe_ports port 70      # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210     # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280     # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488     # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591     # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777     # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localnet
http_access allow all
icp_access allow localnet
icp_access deny all
http_port 3128
hierarchy_stoplist cgi-bin ?
 cache_dir ufs c:/squid/var/cache 9000 16 256
 maximum_object_size 4096000000 KB
access_log c:/squid/var/logs/access.log squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:       1440    20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:    1440    0%  1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0 0%  0
refresh_pattern .       0   20% 4320
 range_offset_limit 409600000 KB
acl shoutcast rep_header X-HTTP09-First-Line ^ICY.[0-9]
upgrade_http0.9 deny shoutcast
acl apache rep_header Server ^Apache
broken_vary_encoding allow apache
visible_hostname localhost 
coredump_dir c:/squid/var/cache
```

The full config can be found here: http://pastebin.com/yRV6VE16

Comment: The example you gave (http://audaupdate.audatex.cz/MASTER_APP/FULL/MODEL/GRAPHIC/0000/GRA/0JD050/0JD050.GFF.ZIP) requires authentication.

These files are typically not cached. Do you have another example of an URL that you think should be cached, but isn't?

Comment: This is main thing i need to fix, so is there a chance how can i let squid cache files which required auth?

Comment: refresh_pattern has an option to ignore auth:

ignore-auth caches responses to requests with authorization,
  as if the originserver had sent ``Cache-control: public''
  in the response header. Doing this VIOLATES the HTTP standard.
  Enabling this feature could make you liable for problems which
  it causes.

See here: http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/refresh_pattern/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Squid is not able to keep objects coming from CDNs like YouTube or URLs with '?' char.
To cache videos, images, etc... from CDN URLs, you should use a plugin that'll do the job for you.
You can try the SquidVideoBooster taking care 600+ websites including YouTube, DailyMotion, NetFlix, etc...

Link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/squidvideosbooster/
Compatible Squid 2.7, 3.4 and 3.5.

Download this plugin and test, you'll see if it fits your needs ;o)

Bye Fred